# Is the inequality $(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y})^2 \geqslant 0$ always true for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^+$?

Tags: number-theory, inequality, real-numbers

Suppose $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^+$

Then is the following inequality true?

$(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y})^2 \geqslant 0$

If it is not true then please provide an example of why it fails.

Comment: **Hint:** the left-hand side is squared.

Comment: The inequality $a^2\geq 0$ is true for every $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Right I know that. It's obvious that the statement is true, but a TA mentioned that I can't start a proof with any statement squared because it isn't necessarily true.

Comment: It sounds like the TA has no successfully explained what she or he thinks is wrong with your argument

Comment: ? What did the TA say *exactly*, and in which context?

Comment: That is not the same thing. This is not true for $x=y=-1$ for instance. Are you still assuming $x,y>0$ in your "conjecture"? *(was replying to a comment since deleted by the OP: "conjecture: $\frac{x+y}{2}\geq \sqrt{xy}$")*

Comment: Wouldn't be the first time someone above me doesn't understand what I'm saying.

Comment: How about this: give us the context in which you did this and what your TA said.

Comment: I can't write a proof in the comments because every time I press enter the comment finishes.

Comment: I'm giving up here, as you don't seem to be willing to state where this issue arose in the first place.

Comment: He said that I can't just square anything. I can't start from a False antecedent because then I could prove anything. But you guys are saying that it isn't false.

Comment: @Sirknow-a-ton To write on the next line you need to press Shift+Enter

Comment: CONJECTURE: $\frac{x+y}{2} \geqslant \sqrt{xy}$

DIRECT PROOF:

GIVEN: Suppose $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^+$

It is clear that $(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y})^2 \geqslant 0$ is always true.

$\implies x - 2\sqrt{xy} + y \geqslant 0$

$\implies x+ y \geqslant 2\sqrt{xy}$


$\implies \frac{x+y}{2} \geqslant \sqrt{xy}$

Comment: Look what I wrote before. $\sqrt{x}$ is not even **defined** if $x<0$. Your conjecture is false, take for instance $x=y=-1$. The issue is not taking the square, it is taking the square **root**.

Comment: @Clement C. x and y are in the POSITIVE REALS. Refresh the page and read the question.

Comment: You just edited your comment to add this, it was written "Suppose $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$" in your ["conjecture"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2971658/is-the-inequality-sqrtx-sqrty2-geqslant-0-always-true-for-x-y-in#comment6133770_2971658). That's it, good night..

Comment: I can redesign the comments section if you want. Gosh we are an impatient bunch aren't we? Mathematicians.

Comment: Bless your heart, Sir know-a-ton.

Comment: Lights and clockwork. Read the initial question not the comments.

Answer (score 4):

Since $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^+$

$\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{y}$ are $\in \mathbb{R}^+$

So 
$\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}\in \mathbb{R}$

Thus $(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2\geq0$

Comment: Yup there it is, thanks!